# Setting form fields in django class based generic view CreateView

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm using django's `CreateView` to add images to a book. I pass the book's id to the class based view as a parameter in the url. Form fields such as `book` and `language` are not rendered on the template, rather they're obtained with the help of the book's id.

```
# views.py
class PictureCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Upload
    fields = "__all__"
    book_id = None

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(PictureCreateView, self).get_initial()
        initial = initial.copy()
        self.book_id = self.kwargs['book_id']
        book = Book.objects.get(id=self.book_id)
        initial['book'] = book
        initial['language'] = language
        initial['uploader'] = self.request.user
        return initial

    # set book_id so it used in the template
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PictureCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['book_id'] = self.book_id
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        print('Form is valid')
        self.object = form.save()
        files = [serialize(self.object)]
        data = {'files': files}
        response = JSONResponse(data, mimetype=response_mimetype(self.request))
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=files.json'
        return super(PictureCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print('Form invalid!')
        print(form.errors)
        data = json.dumps(form.errors)
        return HttpResponse(content=data, status=400, content_type='application/json')

# models.py
class Upload(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path, help_text='Image to process')
    uploader = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, models.CASCADE, related_name='uploader')
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, models.CASCADE)
```

The problem is that I get an error saying the form is invalid, and the fields `uploader`, `book` and `language` are required. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `initial` data is used to display the defaults when the form is initially displayed. It isn't used when those values are missing from the submitted form data. If fields like `book` and `uploader` are set from the URL or logged-in user, then you should leave them out of the form completely, instead of setting them in the initial data. You can then set the values on the instance in the `form_valid` method before the form is saved.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class PictureCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Upload
    fields = ['other_field1', 'other_field2', ...]  # leave out book, language and uploader

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.book_id = self.kwargs['book_id']
        book = Book.objects.get(id=self.book_id)
        form.instance.book = book
        form.instance.language = ????
        form.instance.uploader = self.request.user
        return super(
```

The [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) makes sure that only logged-in users can access the view.

You may want to use `get_object_or_404` to handle the case where `book_id` refers to a book that does not exist.

Comment: Slight modification to your answer - use 'fields' instead of 'exclude', since CreateView needs the 'fields' attribute to be declared.

Comment: I've changed the answer to use `fields` - I had forgotten that `ModelFormMixin` does not support `exclude`.

Answer (score 2):

One thought, initial doesn't fill the model for submission. You need to do that in **init**

```
def __init__(self):
    super(PictureCreateView, self).__init__()
    self.fields['book'] = self.initial['book']
    self.fields['uploader'] = self.initial['uploader']
    self.fields['language'] = self.initial['book']
```

Or, if you don't want to set the fields, make sure they are optional in your original model:

```
class Upload(models.Model):
    uploader = models.ForeignKey('uploader', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    book = models.ForeignKey('book', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    language = models.ForeignKey('language', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: `self.initial['book']` `self.initial['uploader']`are not set when the view is initialised, so the first approach is not going to work. The OP doesn't want the fields to be optional, they want them to be set based on the `book_id` and logged in user.